# Insert if records do not exist in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure which needs to do an insert if the record has not already been inserted.

This stored procedure can be run multiple times by a user. I am using SQL Server 2008

My query is as below. It does not give any error but also does not do anything. If I remove the If not exist and just do a simple insert with the select it works for the first time and then gives an error as the record is present already.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadRecords
   @ADD_BY varchar(10)
  ,@YEAR varchar(4)
  ,@Inserted int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OFF char(2)
DECLARE @Year char(4)
DECLARE @ID varchar(9)

set @Inserted =0

/*check if record exists or not */

IF NOT EXISTS(

Select F.OFF, (@YEAR ), F.ID, F.Form, @ADD_BY

from Table1 as F

Left Join Table2  R
ON F.ID = R.ID
and F.OFF = R.OFF
and F.Year = R.Year

where F.Year = (@Year -1 )

and @OFF= F.OFF
and @Year = F.Year
and @ID= F.ID
and @Form = F.Form
)
/*insert values if records do not exist */

INSERT INTO Table1 (
    OFF, YEAR, ID, Form ,ADD_BY)
Values(@OFF, @Year, @ID , @Form, @ADD_BY)   


SET @Inserted =@@ROWCOUNT

END
GO
```

Comment: **OK**. You've been a SO member for 2 years, and asked 105 questions, and **never** actually bothered to format one yourself. You need to learn how to use the editor, and stop relying on everybody else to fix your broken questions.

Comment: Why not just do the `INSERT` without checking, and `CATCH` the primary key violation if it fails? If you expect most inserts to succeed, this is a lot easier, and it avoids the concurrency issue in your code that another session may `INSERT` the same values after your session `SELECT`s but before it `INSERT`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem with the conditions you added on the `IF NOT EXISTS`, specifically these conditions are the opposite:

```
where F.Year = (@Year -1 )
and @Year = F.Year
```

That will always be false.